# what does $(this) mean in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Demo</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var headings = $('h3');
            var paras = $('p');
            paras.hide().eq(0).show();
            headings.click(function() {
                var cur = $(this); //save the element that has been clicked for easy referal
                cur.siblings('p').hide(); //hide all the paragraphs
                cur.next('p').show(); //get the next paragraph after the clicked header and show it
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            p,h3 {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
            p {height: 150px; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black;}
            h3 {height: 50px; width: 200px; background-color: blue; color: white; border: 1px solid black;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Item 1 </h3>
        <p>Item 1 content</p>
        <h3>Item 2 </h3>
        <p>Item 2 content</p>
        <h3>Item 3 </h3>
        <p>Item 3 content</p>
        <h3>Item 4</h3>
        <p>Item 4 content</p>
    </body>    
</html>
```

Above code is taken from here: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/jquery-for-complete-beginners-part-3/

Question:

for this line: `var cur = $(this);` I know `this` means the `h3` that has been clicked, but why we can not write this way: `var cur = this;` what is the difference between `this` and `$(this)` here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(this)
```

converts the DOM element returned by `this` to a jQuery object, from which, you can continue using jQuery on.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is a reference to the member that invokes the current function

For example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").click(function(){

var jQuerizedElement = $( this ); // instead of calling it by its selector you can use this
  });
});
```

Now you can do more stuff with it.

Answer (score 2):

`this` returns the DOM element, whereas `$(this)` returns the jQuery object.

```
this
```

is equivalent to

```
$(this).get()
```

Answer (score 0):

`$` is the shorthand for the jQuery function. You could also write:

```
var cur = jQuery(this);
```

jQuery "wraps" around DOM elements and other objects in order to give them more functionality. Just like you pass a selector string into the jQuery constructor, you can pass a native DOM element (which `this` is) and it'll become a jQuery object.