# Upload a file using ajax for PHP using: TypeError

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload

I'm actually try to upload an image file by using jQuery ajax method. But I still have two errors. 
The form is so big and have multiple input file. The goal is to upload files during the time user type in other fields. So, the submit button is used for the action, the action is based on image selection. When one input file change, the AJAX code must work.

I tried to find a solution on stackoverflow since 1h turning around few differents syntaxes but nothing work.

My code is here

```html
<form id="form_animation" method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' accept-charset='UTF-8' action=''>
    <!-- something like 2 fieldsets and 15 input before my input file -->
    <input type="file" name="animation_01_file" id="animation_01_file" data-line="1" accept="image/*">
   <!-- few others input -->
</form>
```

jQuery side

```
$("input[type='file']").on('change', function(){

    var form = $(this).get(0);
    var fd = new FormData(form);

    /*var file = $(this).prop('files')[0];
    var fd = new FormData();
    console.log(file);
    fd.append('file', file);*/

    /* var fd = new FormData( $('#form_animation')[0] );
    ===> return error type 'append'
    */


    $.post(
    "traitements_ajax.php", {
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
                cache: false
    },
        function myResult(text_result){
            //some results here
        },
        "text"
    );
```

You can see an other try in comment.

Errors are always :

> TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.

or

> TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor does not implement interface HTMLFormElement.

Really thank you for your time.

Comment: There is no "php" here. Enable error reporting and check the console.

Comment: Edit your tag and title, there is no PHP code

Comment: did u tried the solutions?

Comment: I will edit my post to add more context, because my input file is not the only one entry in the form. Then the goal is to use datas with PHP, so it's why "php" is on tag list

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var dataPost = new FormData($("#formId")[0]);
  var url = "traitements_ajax.php";
  $.ajax({
     url: url,
     type: "POST",
     data:dataPost,
     success:function(result){
      
  }, 
  cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    error:function(error) {

    }   
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formId" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="animation_01_file" id="animation_01_file" data-line="1" accept="image/*">
</form>
```

Recently same problem happened to me. Here is my code. It's working for me. Please check if useful to you.

put file upload button in a form.

Comment: Hey! That's seam to work. Actually I fall in success function. I will try to continue PHP side and check the solve button.
I have impression that $.post() was the real problem. $.ajax() work.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your `<form>` id here:

```
var form = $(this).get(0);
```

Here, `this` means you are trying to get `type="file"` data which is wrong.

you need to use your form id here as like:

```
var form = $("#yourFormID").get(0);
```

Your form example:

```
<form id="yourFormID" enctype="multipart/form-data">......
```

Or, just simple use:

```
var fd = new FormData($("#yourFormID")[0]);
```

Some useful link:

[what does $(this) mean in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182095/what-does-this-mean-in-jquery)

Comment: Thank you, really, but this try make pop the first error message. Maybe the context of my code will help you understand my problem? I just edited it

Comment: cant able to get u @MichaëlCrofte